# Why each subsequent log entry is repeated (using java.util.logging)?

Tags: java, java.util.logging

I have a test and I would like to log some information from the test. I manage to do that using basic java logger, but I'm doing something wrong. Each subsequent entry log message gets multiplied, ie. first message is logged once, second one two times, third one three times, etc. and I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. The messages are pushed to the console also, but there only once.

```
public class MyExampleTest {
    private FileHandler fh = null;
    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(MyExampleTest.class.getName());
    SimpleFormatter formatter = new SimpleFormatter();

    @Test
    public void infoPackage() throws Exception {
        fh = new FileHandler("test.log", true);
        // do some test stuff
        writeEntryToLogFile("entry one");
        // do some more test stuff
        writeEntryToLogFile("entry two");
        // do even more test stuff
        writeEntryToLogFile("entry three");
    }

    private void writeEntryToLogFile(String message) throws Exception {
        fh.setFormatter(formatter); 
        logger.addHandler(fh);
        logger.info(message);
    }

}
```

My log file ends up like this :

```
entry one
entry two
entry two
entry three
entry three
entry three
```

I guess I'm messing something up with the file handler, but I don't know what.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You add an handler each time you invoke `writeEntryToLogFile()`.
So you have an additional duplicated output at each call.

You should add a setup method where you set the context for each executed test. 
JUnit you are using allows it with the `@Before` annotation:

```
@Before
public void setup() {
    fh = new FileHandler("test.log", true);
    formatter = new SimpleFormatter();
    fh.setFormatter(formatter); 
    logger.addHandler(fh);
}
```

And as a side note, a testing method that asserts nothing doesn't make really sense.

Comment: As a further side note, a testing method that prints a load of text can be annoying and will also slow down your tests.

Comment: It's a selenium test. It does stuff, but I cut this from code as it's irrelevant to the problem I was facing. It's not a lot of text, but I want to have some values that are randomly generated logged. Anyhow, your solution looks nice, but it throws a nullpointer. I guess it's because file handler is declared later in @test?

Comment: @tom You was right to cut it. It makes the problem more visible.  Now to indicate cut code, adding `...` is better. Otherwise, yes you are right.`fh = new FileHandler("test.log", true);` should be executed in the setup() method. I updated to be correct.

Comment: "some values that are randomly generated logged" *Do not use* randomly generated values in your tests. When your tests fail, you want to be fairly certain it's because something was broken or changed - not because *what you were testing* changed.

Answer (score 3):

Try moving below statements inside `infoPackage()` method

`fh.setFormatter(formatter); 
 logger.addHandler(fh);`

As these are getting set multiple times because of method calls.

Answer (score 2):

You're adding the same handler every time you add a message. You should only do this once. I suggest a static initialiser.

I've commented out the lines that you no longer need:

```
public class MyExampleTest {
    //private FileHandler fh = null;
    private static final Logger logger;
    //SimpleFormatter formatter = new SimpleFormatter();

    static {
        logger = Logger.getLogger(MyExampleTest.class.getName());
        FileHandler fh = new FileHandler("test.log", true);
        fh.setFormatter(new SimpleFormatter());
        logger.addHandler(fh);
    }

    @Test
    public void infoPackage() throws Exception {
        //fh = new FileHandler("test.log", true);
        // do some test stuff
        writeEntryToLogFile("entry one");
        // do some more test stuff
        writeEntryToLogFile("entry two");
        // do even more test stuff
        writeEntryToLogFile("entry three");
    }

    private void writeEntryToLogFile(String message) throws Exception {
        //fh.setFormatter(formatter); 
        //logger.addHandler(fh);
        logger.info(message);
    }
}
```

It's worth noting that `writeEntryToLogFile` is now a little bit pointless because it's only a single line. I'd get rid of that function.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is because you are calling `writeEntryToLogFile()` multiple times and setting the `fileHandler` multiple times.

Move the 2 lines in the calling method as:

```
@Test
public void infoPackage() throws Exception {
    fh = new FileHandler("test.log", true);
    fh.setFormatter(formatter); 
    logger.addHandler(fh);
    // do some test stuff
    writeEntryToLogFile("entry one");
    // do some more test stuff
    writeEntryToLogFile("entry two");
    // do even more test stuff
    writeEntryToLogFile("entry three");
}

private void writeEntryToLogFile(String message) throws Exception {
    logger.info(message);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just to elaborate on what Krishna Kuntala said, when you look at the [Logger](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/logging/Logger.html) class, the add handler is adding on an [ArrayList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html).

```
private final CopyOnWriteArrayList <Handler> handlers
```

Since you are calling the add handler the third time when you are on the entry three, it will log the same statement using the three handlers which output to the same file.